# XSLT to extract specific elements in irregular XML into csv format

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I have a XML file which is irregular/not formatted. The structure looks like this-

```
<Host> 
 <element1>type0</element1>
 <element2>Fruits</element2>
 <NodeA>
   <element1>type1</element1>
   <element2>Fruits</element2>
   <NodeB>
     <element1>type2</element1>
     <element2>Fruits</element2>
     <NodeC>
       <element1>type3</element1>
       <element2>Fruits</element2>
       <NodeD>
         <element1>type4</element1>
         <element2>Vegetables</element2>
       </NodeD>
     </NodeC>
   </NodeB>
 </NodeA>
 <NodeE>
   <element1>type5</element1>
   <element2>Fruits</element2>
   <NodeF>
     <element1>type6</element1>
     <element2>Vegetables</element2>
   </NodeF> 
 </NodeE>  
</Host>
```

I want to extract `<element1>` from the XML in a CSV format. Which means all the values of `<element1>` should be extracted as -

```
type0,type1,type2,type3,type4,type5,type6
```

I have tried the below XSLT but I am getting the elements in tabular format. I couldn't be able to get data in the above format.
XSLT written -

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <table border="1">
    <xsl:for-each select="//element1">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any answer/suggestion would be a great help. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a CSV result, then get rid of all the HTML code and just add a comma where it's needed:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//element1">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi @Michael.hor257k, Thanks for the answer. What would be the logic if I wish to see the output in single quotations? like 'type0','type1','type2',...

Comment: @QATesting Add `<xsl:text>'</xsl:text>` before and after the value.

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k, I have an additional requirement where I have to group 1000 values of <element1> into one set. I am extracting the values in  'type0','type1','type2',....'typen' format and passing as an input to sql query IN condition which allow only 1000 values. Now I want to group 1000 values into one set and pass it into the query. Could you please help me on this